Django Celery Revoke not terminating the task
I have a Django celery on my project and I have set everything and working well but I want to be able to terminate tasks after it starts processing. eg., I backup my database through backend tasks and any time I can decide to cancel the tasks so it can terminate the process but when I use:
from project.celery import app res = app.control.terminate(task_id=task_id
This is just returning None without teminating the task.
The task still keeps running.
I have also used revoke which is still the same
I am using this doc celery
Is there anyway to terminate it or am I missing a setting?
